# How to programmatically create rectangle and textblock with binding element with c#?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, binding, visiblox

I have the following code, which i want to programmatically create. Where the *i* is must be an integer into xaml! This is a sample Code from VISIBLOX.

```
<Rectangle Margin="20,0,0,5" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Series[i].LineStroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Series[i].DataSeries.Title}"  />
        <TextBlock Margin="4,0,0,0"  Text="(" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Behaviour.Behaviours[0].CurrentPoints[i].Y, StringFormat=0.00}" Width="38" />
        <TextBlock Text=")" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

I can create a most programmatically but im stucking since 2 days with the **Path=Behaviour.Behaviours[0].CurrentPoints[i].Y** impossible for me to see how i can programmatically create it!

Thank u for help

**Edit**

**IT's Work**

```
TextBlock txtBlock3 = new TextBlock();
Binding txtBinding3 = new Binding();
txtBinding3.ElementName = "MainChart";
txtBinding3.Path = new PropertyPath("Behaviour.Behaviours[0].CurrentPoints[" + index +"].Y");
txtBlock3.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, txtBinding3);
txtBlock3.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
Panel.Children.Add(txtBlock3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're going to be building this Binding in a for loop of some sort?

If so, can't you do something like:

```
Binding b = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Behaviour.Behaviours[0].CurrentPoints[" + i +"].Y”) };
```

Where the i there is the indexer in the for loop?  I'm not sure I fully understand the problem so maybe you could elaborate with a bit more context?

If you’re trying to bind to a different thing depending on what is available in CurrentPoints, you might need to just bind to Benaviour.Behaviours[0] and use a converter to return the correct point’s Y value.

If you need any more help just let me know!

Comment: Hi Grant, u really get the point i'm into a for loop! i try ur method but it dont work! look my Edit